# How to read fixed chunk of lines (say 100) from stdin in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, stdin, readline

I want to read first 100 lines from stdin, convert it into a dataframe, do some processing with it. Then read the next 100 lines(101-200) from stdin, convert it into a dataframe, do some processing...and so forth

readlines() in python doesn't have any argument to specify the number of lines to be read.

readLines() in R has this but I am not able to do the same in python.

Appreciate any help in this.

Comment: What's wrong with `readline()` in a counting loop?

Comment: the pandas library has chunksize arguments to many of its read_* functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `sys.stdin`. It has a file interface, true to the unix philosophy. This means that you can iterate on it to get lines. After that, you just have to slice it like any iterator -- I'd suggest itertools https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html.

```
import sys
import itertools

CHUNK_LENGTH = 200

lines_chunk = itertools.islice(sys.stdin, CHUNK_LENGTH)
```

Better yet, use the itertools recipe for grouper and get an iterable of chunks (see the above link)

```
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)

chunks_of_200 = grouper(sys.stdin, CHUNK_LENGTH, fillvalue="")
for chunk_of_200 in chunks_of_200:
     # do something with chunk
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want vanilla Python 3, you could do

```
import sys
lines = [line for _,line in zip(range(200),sys.stdin)]
```